# Stream-process UTF-16 file with BOM and Unix line endings in Windows perl

Tags: perl, unicode, utf-16

I need to stream-process using perl a 1Gb text file encoded in UTF-16 little-endian with unix-style endings (i.e. 0x000A only without 0x000D in the stream) and LE BOM in the beginning. File is processed on Windows (Unix solutions are needed also). By stream-process I mean using while (<>), line-by-line reading and writing.
Would be nice to have a command line one-liner like:
**perl -pe "BEGIN { SOME_PREPARATION }; s/SRC/DST/g;" infile.txt > outfile.txt**

Hex dump of input for testing (two lines: "a" and "b" letters on each):
**FF FE 61 00 0A 00 62 00 0A 00**

processing like **s/b/c/g** should give an output ("b" replaced with "c"):
**FF FE 61 00 0A 00 63 00 0A 00**

PS. Right now with all my trials either there's a problem with CRLF output (0D 0A bytes are output producing incorrect unicode symbol, and I need only 0A00 without 0D00 to preserve same unix style) or every new line switches LE/BE, i.e. same "a" on one line is 6100 on the odd lines and 0061 on the even lines in the output.

Comment: Perl 5.what? There are some variances, and I want to make sure my answer works for yours.

Comment: The reason it's tricky is that Perl adds :crlf before you have a chance to add :encoding(UTF-16le) to the handle, and that puts them in the wrong order.

Comment: @ikegami can you explain :crlf usage? What does it make if present like ":crlf:encoding(UTF-16LE)"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best I've come up with is this:

```
perl -pe "BEGIN { binmode $_, ':raw:encoding(UTF-16LE)' for *STDIN, *STDOUT }; s/b/c/g;" <infile.txt >outfile.txt
```

But note that I had to use `<infile.txt` instead of `infile.txt` so that the file would be on STDIN.  Theoretically, the [open](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?open) pragma should control the encoding used by the magic `ARGV` filehandle, but I can't get it to work correctly in this case.

The difference between `<infile.txt` and `infile.txt` is in how and when the files are opened.  With `<infile.txt`, the file is connected to standard input, and opened before Perl begins running.  When you `binmode STDIN` in a `BEGIN` block, the file is already open, and you can change the encoding.

When you use `infile.txt`, the filename is passed as a command line argument and placed in the `@ARGV` array.  When the `BEGIN` block executes, the file is not open yet, so you can't set its encoding.  Theoretically, you ought to be able to say:

```
use open qw(:std IO :raw:encoding(UTF-16LE));
```

and have the magic `<ARGV>` processing apply the right encoding.  But I haven't been able to get that to work right in this case.

Comment: Wow! Works great! :) Thank you @cjm . As I found out experimenting right now, the main problem of problems in my code was absence of "<" before infile.txt. Can you explain why is it necessary and what kind of difference it makes? If not STDIN so where the file is redirected without "<"? 'Cause   perl -pe "print" file.txt   works well as if file.txt is at STDIN inside the script... BTW, what's the difference between using UTF-16LE and UTF-16 here in the script?

Comment: Why `:raw`? Also, I `use open` all the time with `:utf8` and magic `ARGV`.

Comment: @tchrist, I used `:raw` because he's on Windows, where Perl adds `:crlf` by default, but he wants output with Unix line endings.  I don't know a better way to remove `:crlf`.