# LF --> CR/LF conversion for UTF-16 file

Tags: linux, encoding, command-line, utf-16, line-endings

I have an UTF-16 encoded file and I want replace UNIX line endings with Windows line endings. I don't want to touch anything else.

Is there a linux command line tool that can search for two bytes "0A 00" and replace it with four bytes "0D 00 0A 00"?

Comment: I tried "unix2dos" already. It doesn't work as it replaces "0A 00" to "OD 0A 00"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -we 'binmode STDIN,  ":encoding(UTF-16le)";
          binmode STDOUT, ":encoding(UTF-16le):crlf";
          print while <STDIN>;
        ' < input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work for me. But my coworker just found this:
perl -pe "BEGIN { binmode $_, ':raw:encoding(UTF-16LE)' for *STDIN, *STDOUT }; s/\n\0/\r\0\n\0/g;" < input > output

Comment: @LarsSchneider: Does prepending `:raw` to the binmodes help? But the original works for me, can you show what `xxd input.txt` returns?

Comment: Like this? 'perl -we ':raw:binmode STDIN,  ":encoding(UTF-16le)"; :raw:binmode STDOUT, ":encoding(UTF-16le):crlf"; print while <>; '' ?

Comment: Gives me: Unquoted string "raw" may clash with future reserved word at -e line 1.
syntax error at -e line 1, near "; :"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: @LarsSchneider: No, `':raw:encoding...`. Works for me, with or without BOM, with or without raw.

Comment: Yes I tried that: perl -we 'binmode STDIN,  ":raw:encoding(UTF-16le)"; binmode STDOUT, ":raw:encoding(UTF-16le):crlf"; print while <>; '

This destroys the encoding somehow "FF FE 24 00 73 00 63 00" becomes "FF 00 FE 00 24 00 00 00...". Any idea why? I am no perl expert at all :-)

This is my perl version:
This is perl 5, version 16, subversion 2 (v5.16.2)

Comment: @LarsSchneider: I've got it! After configuring STDIN, we also have to use it: `<STDIN>` and `< input`!

Answer (score 1):

You may use `unix2dos`, but you have to convert the file to a 8-bit encoding before, and back to UTF-16 after. The obvious intermediate candidate is UTF-8:

```
$ cat in.txt | iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF-8 | unix2dos | iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-16 > out.txt
```

You can wrap these three piped commands in a handy script, if you wish.

```
#/bin/sh
iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF-8 | unix2dos | iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-16
```

Answer (score 0):

`unix2dos` is what you're looking for. See its different options to find the one that's right for your UTF-16 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
perl -pe "BEGIN { binmode $_, ':raw:encoding(UTF-16LE)' for *STDIN, *STDOUT }; s/\n\0/\r\0\n\0/g;" < input.file > output.file
```

Credit to my coworker Manu and [Stream-process UTF-16 file with BOM and Unix line endings in Windows perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9447653/stream-process-utf-16-file-with-bom-and-unix-line-endings-in-windows-perl)